# Why may an air passenger experience an electric shock when he touches the door knob of the toilet of an aeroplane flying at a high altitude?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

Why may an air passenger experience an electric shock when he touches the door knob of the toilet of an aeroplane flying at a high altitude?

Comment: Maybe because of the blankets that they hand out. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

Comment: Why don't users here answer questions. I need help with this question

Comment: Might be because as you walk to the toilet, you charge up yourself when walking across the carpet floor (see link in Glen's comment). To increase the chances of someone answering your questions, you could also add additional details of the circumstances under which this occurs and an explanation you came up with. Also, give it some time, 36 min isn't very long yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the electric shock in exactly the same way you get it on the ground: walking around, or (as @Glen suggested) by rubbing the blankets you accumulate electric charge on your body. This charge is transferred to the rest of the system (the plane or the earth) when you touch the knob. Glen's link explains how the charge forms in the first place.

Your question seems to imply that, in order to get the shock, the body somehow has to be connected to earth. That is incorrect. Electricity flows whenever 2 objects at different potentials touch each other, regardless of what else the objects are connected to.

Comment: The problem may well be increased by the dry air conditions in the cabin...

Answer (score 1):

As the passenger walk through the carpeted floor of the plane the passenger might get charged up.So when he holds the metal knob he gives path to the charges to flow so he gets an electric charge.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are ok in the sense that the nylon carpets often used in planes form a very good surface to get charged up with static electricity as you shuffle across it. However, they miss the absolutely crucial point that the air on an aeroplane at high altitude is partly recirculated but partly taken in (and heated) from the environment, which is extremely dry. You must have noticed that on an aeroplane your eyes get itchy and your skin gets dry. That is because the humidity of the air is extremely low - typically about 10 per cent. This means that static is not discharged very easily other than when you grab hold of a conductor.

That is why the shocking effect would most likely *only* occur when the plane was at cruising height.

I get the same problems when working at observatories - where the air is frequently very dry. Getting in an out of cars can be especially problematic. I find that holding the car keys tight and touching the point of them onto the car door when getting in and out saves a painful static discharge to the fingertips.

Answer (score 0):

you exchange charges with knob
your body and the knob has charge difference, charges flow to get equilibrium from high potential to low potential. As charges flow you feel shock.